# Cannot (re)set privileges for debian-sys-maint, error 1045 Access denied

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, mysql-error-1045

My MariaDB Server can not be stopped/restarted without an error.

History:
I was running a MySQL-Server on Lubuntu 14.04. To chance the hard disk, I stored the database with

`mysqldump -u root -p --events --all-databases > dump.sql`

set up the new system (still Lubuntu 14.04), but now with MariaDB, and played back the database with

`mysql -u root -p < dump.sql`

Everything seemed to work well. But now I discovered that a server restart displays an error:

`service mysql stop`

says "fail". After killing and restart with

`service mysql start`

I get the message

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'`

In several forums (also here) is advised to set a neu password for debian-sys-admin with

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on . TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

but this results in the message

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

(while I'm logged in as root).

I need help!

Comment: When you mention user `root` it is the Linux user `root` and not the MySQL user `root`?

Answer (score 1):

In all Debian based distributions the MySQL user `debian-sys-maint` is needed by the package `mysql-server-5.5` to shut down mysql and to do other administration.  So you also need see to that the password of that user is correct in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. You could set it to the propper value from that file to the user with those commands.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('*secret*') WHERE User='debian-sys-maint';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Read `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian.gz` for more information.

The user `debian-sys-maint` also needs all privileges to the `mysql` database and the shutdown privileges. You *MIGHT* try this to set the privileges if they have been removed.

```
GRANT SHUTDOWN ON *.* TO ‘debian-sys-maint’@’localhost’ identified by ‘*secret*';
GRANT all ON mysql.* TO ‘debian-sys-maint’@’localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where `*secret*` is the password set in the file `debian.cnf`.

Comment: I got `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'`, Orz